# VS 2008 with windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7

I've brand new HP laptop with windows 7 home premium. I installed VS 2008 + SP1. It works fine. I installed MVC2. But since yesterday, as soon as I open a view to edit, the VS 2008 becomes unresponsive. Every time I reopen, same thing is happening. I can do other things, like add/edit entity model, add/edit class etc..

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add that this also worked well for a situation I ran into recently for some of our [Business Intelligence Development Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173767.aspx) (BIDS) users.  BIDS, for those who aren't familiar, is a scaled down Visual Studio 2008 instance that can be used to create and deploy SSRS-based reports. However, in order to connect it to, say, TFS 2010, you have to install a number of extra items (Team Explorer 2008, TE 2008 SP1, TE 2008 SP1 Forward Compatibility patch).

Anyway, I and other useres ran into a situation where we lacked the ability to *create* new BI projects. The only options under the 'File' menu were 'New File' and 'New Team Project'.  After closing the client and relaunching using the '`/resetsetting`' command, I regained the options that most other installs had (File → New → Project, Web Site, Team Project, File).

Answer (score 0):

You can try resetting your development environment settings to factory default.  Relaunch VS2008 by using the command:

```
devenv.exe /resetsettings
```

Obviously you'll lose your customizations to your environment by doing this. You can export them to a file first from the Tools menu → Import and Export Settings.  If resetting the settings doesn't work, you can restore them with the command:

```
devenv.exe /resetsettings [PathToSettingsFile]
```